# Regex: until but not including group or group

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

## Intro

I want to capture every block of text starting from newline then ID, until - but not including -, either, next ID, or any string that starts from a new line and follows with capital letters.

Pseudocode:

```
IDENTIFIER = newline + 0-2 UPPERCASE + 2-4 DIGITS + 0-2 UPPERCASE + literal dot + 1-2 space
(?P<id>IDENTIFIER)(?P<text>.*?)(?:(?!(ID|\n[A-Z]?)))
                              ^
                              |--- match until here
```

## Example

Here is example I made using dummy dataset:
https://regex101.com/r/FpLikK/4

## Real dataset

However, I cannot reproduce the example on my real dataset.

I have the following text:

```
Lorem ipsum ...
130A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Q133AR. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum continues on next line, need to capture it as well 
S321V.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
SOME UPPERCASE TEXT I DONT WANT TO CAPTURE.
N999B.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

and a piece of Python code:

```py
import re

regex_id = r"\n[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{2,4}[A-Z]{0,2}\.\ {1,2}"
regex_until_but_not_including = lambda rgx: rf"(?:(?!{rgx}).)*"
regex_everything_non_greedy = '.*?'
regex_or = lambda iterable: '(' + '|'.join([f'({e})' for e in iterable]) + ')'


regex_pattern = (
      regex_id 
    + regex_everything_non_greedy 
    + regex_until_but_not_including(regex_id)
)

text = "Lorem ipsum ...\n130A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nQ133AR. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \nLorem ipsum continues on next line, need to capture it as well \nS321V.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \nSOME UPPERCASE STUFF I DON'T WANT TO MATCH.\nN999B.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

re.findall(
    pattern=regex_pattern,
    string=text, 
    flags=re.DOTALL
)
```

Regex expanded:

```regex
r"\n[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{2,4}[A-Z]{0,2}\.\ {1,2}.*?(?:(?!\n[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{2,4}[A-Z]{0,2}\.\ {1,2}).)*"
```

## Current output

```py
[
 '130A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
 'Q133AR. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nLorem ipsum continues on next line, need to capture it as well ',
 'S321V.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nSOME TEXT STUFF I DONT WANT TO MATCH.',
 'N999B.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
]
```

## Expected output

```py
[
 '130A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
 'Q133AR. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nLorem ipsum continues on next line, need to capture it as well',
 'S321V.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
]
```

## What have I tried

I was hoping that modyfying my code with:

```py
regex_or = lambda iterable: '(' + '|'.join([f'({e})' for e in iterable]) + ')'

regex_pattern = (
      regex_id 
    + regex_everything_non_greedy 
    + regex_until_but_not_including(
        regex_or([regex_id, r'\n[A-Z]+']))
)
```

would yield correct result, but, sadly, it produces a list of empty 3-element tuples.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```py
(?ms)^[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{2,4}[A-Z]{0,2}\.\ {1,2}(?=.*\n[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[A-Z][^\r\na-z]*$).*?(?=\n[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[A-Z][^\r\na-z]*$|[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{2,4}[A-Z]{0,2}\.\ |\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdJmku/2).

The pattern follows the following scheme: `^<ID>(?=.*<UPPERCASE_LINE>)<ANY_TEXT_AS_FEW_AS_POSSIBLE>(?=<UPPERCASE_LINE>|<ID>|<STRING_END>)`.

The part I actually added is `\n[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[A-Z][^\r\na-z]*$` that matches a line with no lowercase letters but has at least one captital letter:

- `\n` - a newline
- `[^\r\na-zA-Z]*` - zero or more chars other than LF, CR and ASCII letters
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[^\r\na-z]*` - zero or more chars other than CR, LF and lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of a line (see the `re.MULTILINE` flag, or `(?m)`, that redefine this anchor behavior).

Here is the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CDjvNl):

```py
import re
regex_id = r"[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{2,4}[A-Z]{0,2}\.\ {1,2}"
regex_uppercaseline = r"\n[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[A-Z][^\r\na-z]*$"
regex_pattern = fr"^{regex_id}(?=.*{regex_uppercaseline}).*?(?={regex_uppercaseline}|\n{regex_id}|\Z)"

text = "Lorem ipsum ...\n130A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nQ133AR. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \nLorem ipsum continues on next line, need to capture it as well \nS321V.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \nSOME UPPERCASE STUFF I DON'T WANT TO MATCH.\nN999B.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

res = re.findall(regex_pattern, text, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
print(res)
# => ['130A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
#     'Q133AR. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \nLorem ipsum continues on next line, need to capture it as well ',
#     'S321V.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. '
#    ]
```

Comment: this is great idea, but is it possible to modify it in a way that `N999B.  ...` isn't included in results? I included it as an edge case, where the phrase matching `regex_id` occurs after UPPERCASE TEXT, and since it occurs after UPPERCASE TEXT, it should not be included in results.


While writing this comment, I realized I probably need optional non-capturing positive lookahead for UPPERCASE TEXT... But I still don't know how to "end" regex search when it hits that pattern... Can you help?

Comment: removing `|\Z` does the trick (at least at the first glance), I'm yet to understand why

Comment: @Marcin `|\Z` allows matching the last match. If you do not need the last match (at the end of the string), removing `|\Z` is a valid fix. Edit: after reading the top comment, I realize this is not the right fix. But what is the real rule then? Should matching stop after an UPPERCASE line altogether?

Comment: Ad. edit: yes exactly. My apologies as the whole question and title are misformulated... Real title should be **match X until (not including) next X, and stop matching altogather when encountering Y**, where `Y = \n[A-Z\s]*\n` and `X = regex_id`

Comment: @Marcin Ok, you need to add `(?=.*\n[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[A-Z][^\r\na-z]*$)` after the first ID pattern, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdJmku/2).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
for s in re.sub(f'^[A-Z\s{string.punctuation}]*\n', '', text, flags=re.M).split('\n'):
    if re.match(r'^\w+\.\s+', s):
        l += [s]
    elif l:
        l[-1] = "\n".join([l[-1], s])
print(l)
```

results in:

```
['130A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
 'Q133AR. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nLorem ipsum continues on next line, need to capture it as well ',
 'S321V.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ',
 'N999B.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.']
```

Which, if I'm looking at the correct field this time, is what you wanted.  I'm not sure I matched on exactly the right thing. But the general strategy is to delete all the lines that are all caps (and no numbers), punctuation, and spaces.  Then, for each line, if it starts with "word.(one or more spaces)" then append this to the list "l".  If it doesn't match that, and it's not the first line, then join it to the last item in list "l".

I can't reconcile from your description why the last row is not included in your desired output.